# Load a properties file into a java.util.Properties?

Tags: java, spring, properties

I need to inject a `java.utils.Properties` instance into one of my beans. Is there a Spring class which will load the properties file and convert it into a `java.utils.Properties` instance, ready for injection?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, using `<util:properties>` (see [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties)).

Example:

```
<!-- creates a java.util.Properties instance with values loaded from the supplied location -->
<util:properties id="jdbcConfiguration" location="classpath:com/foo/jdbc-production.properties"/>
```